# Need onclick to change image and count

Tags: html, count, onclick, buttonclick

I have no coding skills, building a tribute website for my best friend who passed, want a tribute candle like other memorial sites have. You see an image of an unlit candle, some text says "Light a Candle" - you click it, the image changes to a lit candle and some text says "23 candles have been lit for Inez" or whatever the count is of course.

I've made her site on wix, which only allows for html and flash codes to be added. I've spent two days trying to piece something together and it's just not working. Please have mercy on a non coder so I can get her site live.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at this:

https://rapidapi.com/#ourfeatures

> RapidAPI let’s you build the backend for your app easily - without writing a single line of code. With RapidAPI you can use blocks to construct your backend logic. From saving to a database to proccesing payments

[Instructions here](http://rapidsoftwaresolutions.github.io/documentation/#implementing-it-in-your-app)